Expo-Router [V3] fails to encounter routes on production builds
I am using expo-router v3 with the new Expo SDK 51 on a new app. I have these routes on my root _layout file:
<ThemeProvider value={DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(public)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack>
 </ThemeProvider>

When running on Expo Go or in Development builds the app works just fine but when trying to run on a preview or production build it fails to encounter the (tabs) routes. I can navigate through the public ones but when trying to access the tabs screens it fails. Any help on this would be very appreciated.
I have tried downgrade the version of expo-router but still in v3 it fails.
